# Getting SQL Exception ORA-08103: object no longer exists in java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, sys-refcursor

Below is my procedure signature:

```
PROCEDURE sp_trx(i_arr_Sust  IN    T_TAB_SUST,
                            o_locator_map    OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR,
                            o_pkid_map   OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR,
                            o_error    OUT   VARCHAR2)
```

And below is my ref cursor inside procedure:

```
   OPEN o_locator_map FOR
    SELECT c_uuid,
          c_id,
          r_locator,
          TO_CHAR(cj_creation_date, g_dt_format) c_date,
          TO_CHAR(cj_last_modified_date, g_dt_format) cj_last_modified_date,
          version_number
    FROM tmp_locator_map;
```

Below is data type in oracle:

```
c_uuid-->VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), c_id--> NUMBER, r_locator--> VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
```

And below is my Java process for procedure:

```
String insertStoreProc = "{call PKG_LOADER.sp_trx(?,?,?,?)}";
CallableStatement callableStatement  = con.prepareCall(insertStoreProc);
            callableStatement.setObject(1, returninParam, 2003);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            callableStatement.execute();
            Object obj_recordLoc = callableStatement.getObject(2);
            ResultSet rset =((OracleCallableStatement) callableStatement).getCursor(2);

            while (rset.next()){
                 String c_uuid = rset.getString(1);
                      }
```

Now Problem is i'm getting below mention exception at **rset.next()**:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08103: object no longer exists

Kindly suggest.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `o_pkid_map` and `o_error` are only defined in procedure arguments, however those are not being used in your code snippet and in Java code, you are trying to fetch those two which do not return any records from procedure.

Comment: And `callableStatement.getObject(2);` index is same as of `((OracleCallableStatement) callableStatement).getCursor(2);`

Comment: o_locator_map is also defined in procedure as o_locator_map    OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR and i know Object obj_recordLoc = callableStatement.getObject(2); and ((OracleCallableStatement) callableStatement).getCursor(2); are same but i'm just trying to check better option.

Comment: Is there any index number mismatch? See my second comment.

Comment: No, I'm fetching o_locator_map which is second Index in procedure declaration. And which I'm getting fetching using ResultSet rset =((OracleCallableStatement) callableStatement).getCursor(2);

Comment: `callableStatement.getObject(2);` and `((OracleCallableStatement) callableStatement).getCursor(2);` are having same index, is this correct?

Comment: yes both are same you can ignore it callableStatement.getObject(2);

Answer (score 1):

the `next()` API states the following :

`When a call to the next method returns false, the cursor is positioned after the last row. Any invocation of a ResultSet method which requires a current row will result in a SQLException being thrown. If the result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,` ***`it is vendor specified whether their JDBC driver implementation will return false or throw an SQLException on a subsequent call to next.`***

so you may encounter this Excpetion when the cursor reaches the end of the ResultSet